# Can the OR operator be used in SOSL queries?

Tags: apex, query, sosl

Trying to do a SOSL query to find object matches for one of two variables. The following query is very simplified for easy reading. Any help is appreciated.

```
String queryString = 'FIND :var1 OR :var2 IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Name);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use OR operator in SOSL as well but variable expression can't be used this way as far as I know:

This Example Works:

```
List<List<sObject>> l = [FIND '"Jhon" OR "Doe"'
                     IN Name Fields
                     RETURNING Account(name, phone)];
```